# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'currencies' of undefined at HTMLSelectElement.showFinances

Tags: javascript

i really need your help, please. I´m still a beginner and i got really stuck. 
I´m trying to display the currency buy price, but it is only displaying on the console, not on the web page. I have no idea what im doing wrong.
When i try to change the currency with the eventlistener, the console shows the message in the image, but the currency buy price in shown on the console.

image link https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3Ezu.jpg

That´s the code:

```js
        // Set variables
const section = document.querySelector('section');
const select = document.querySelector('select');
const para = document.querySelector('p');

// Request API
fetch('https://api.hgbrasil.com/finance?format=json-cors&key=fef8f745')
.then(res => res.json())
.then(json => showFinances(json))

// Add change currency function
select.addEventListener('change', showFinances);

function showFinances(jsonObj) {
    const finances2 = jsonObj;
    const choice = select.value;

    switch (choice) {
        case 'dollar':
            para.textContent = 'A Cotação do Dolar é: ' + finances2['results']['currencies']['USD'].buy;
            break;
        case 'libra':
            para.textContent = 'A Cotação da Libra é: ';
            break;
        case 'euro':
            para.textContent = 'A cotação do Euro é: ';
            break;
        default:
            para.textContent = '';
    }

    console.log(finances2['results']['currencies']['USD'].buy)
}
```

Comment: `finances2` already is `jsonObj['results'].currencies.USD.buy` that is why `finances2['results']['currencies']['USD']['buy']` and `finances2[USD].buy` fail on `para.textContent`. Just use `finances2` there as well since it is already assigned or restart from `jsonObj['results']` . `finances2` does not contains `currencies` `jsonObj['results']` does.

Answer (score 0):

Check in debug what is being returned in jsonObj, it looks like it doesn't have a ['results'] element (it is undefined).  If the method is being triggered by the change event on the select, then it won't have a json object, it will have the event object.

Comment: The ['results'] element exists. I tried the same code without the change event, and it worked fine, but i want to mak a change between the currencies, and i thought the change event would work

Comment: Then you need `select.addEventListener('change', function(){showFinances(json);})`
to pass the json object to that function.

Comment: Check what is being passed in to the function as your json parameter. Is it what you expect?